# Analyzing Logs though ELK Stack

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am using ELK Stack to analyze the logs generated by my Spring Boot application. Below is the sample structure of my generated logs.

Logs:

> 13-04-2020 10:53:40.074 INFO  16688 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] c.i.e.util.SavingEquityData : Saving the record - equityFeeds in the database as well as in REDIS cache.

I want to monitor my logs through the ELK Stack.

Logstash.conf

```
input {
  file {
    type => "syslog"
    path => ["C:/temp/equityFeedsProcessing.log"]
    start_position => "beginning" 
  }
}

filter {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{LOGLEVEL:log-level} %{DATA:class}:%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }      
    } 
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  }
}
```

I do understand the input and output plugins. What I do not understand is the filter plugin. Although I have written a Grok filter below which passes in the Grok debugger: `https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/`

Pattern:

```
%{LOGLEVEL:log-level} %{DATA:class}:%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

Output:

```
{
  "log": [
    [
      "INFO"
    ]
  ],
  "class": [
    [
      " 2568 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] c.i.e.util.JAXBDateDeSerializer "
    ]
  ],
  "message": [
    [
      " Inside Unmarshall method of JAXB Date Deserializer."
    ]
  ]
}
```

1. I haven't been able to map all the fields in the filter plugin
   for e.g. the timestamp field.  How do I do this?
2. How do I create the indices. I do understand that I can see the indices created at
   `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices/?v`
3. I also understand that for creating the indices we have to go to Kibana -> Management ->
   Index patterns -> Create Index pattern. I am not able to create my
   Index patterns here. Is it because I have not given them in the
   logstash.conf file. If Yes How do I do that?
4. Also, after creating the Index patterns I understand that we have to go to Discover and
   then select the Index Pattern. I am not able to see my logs here.

As mentioned above my basic aim is to analyze and monitor the logs (period). I am not able to create proper filter and create indices. I searched the net but unable to find a place where this shown in detail and from beginner level.  Everything seems to be too complex.

Comment: Any answers please to above query?

Comment: Any answer or directions please.

Answer (score 0):

## Map fields

Start with the following pattern for your example log (it contains a custom pattern - `MSG`):

```
%{DATESTAMP:log_timestamp}\s*%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}\s*%{POSINT:logged_for_pid}\s*--- \[+%{NOTSPACE:logged_for_thread}+\]\s*%{JAVACLASS:logger}\s*%{MSG:log_message}
```

You can validate it in the [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/):
[image]

The `filter` in the `logstash.conf` file with this pattern looks like this:

```
# logstash.conf
…
filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
        match => {
            "message" => "%{DATESTAMP:log_timestamp}\s*%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}\s*%{POSINT:logged_for_pid}\s*--- \[+%{NOTSPACE:logged_for_thread}+\]\s*%{JAVACLASS:logger}\s*%{MSG:log_message}"
        }
    }
}
…
```

### Custom patterns

As you can see I told grok to look for my [custom patterns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns) in the `patterns` directory which I put in the same location as my `logstash.conf` file. In this directory I created the `custom.txt` file with the following content:

```
# patterns/custom.txt
MSG \s:.*
```

#### Removing redundant fields in Grok Debugger output with custom patterns

If you don't like how the timestamp was printed in the Grok Debugger interface, check out the `DATESTAMP` in [grok-patterns](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns). To create the following pattern I replaced every element of the `DATESTAMP` with corresponding regular expression (one by one directly in the Grok Debugger, it's too complex to replace everything at once):

```
CUSTOM_DATE (?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9])[./-](?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[./-](?>\d\d){1,2}[- ](?!<[0-9])(?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::(?:(?:[0-5][0-9]|60)(?:[:.,][0-9]+)?))(?![0-9])
```

Result:
[image]

If you want (the Logstash output will stay the same), you can add this new pattern in a new line in the `custom.txt` file, and update the `match`:

```
# logstash.conf
…
match => {
            "message" => "%{CUSTOM_DATE:log_timestamp}\s*%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}\s*%{POSINT:logged_for_pid}\s*--- \[+%{NOTSPACE:logged_for_thread}+\]\s*%{JAVACLASS:logger}\s*%{MSG:log_message}"
        }
…
```

## Define index in Logstash configuration

I defined an example index in the [output defined for elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#_writing_to_different_indices_best_practices):

```
# logstash.conf
…
output {
    elasticsearch {
        …
        index => "example-index-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

You should be able to choose something like the `example-index*` while creating indices in Kibana.

## Useful resources

- [Available patterns](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns) that I used in my solution
- [What to do when part of one field got caught in a different pattern](https://keepgrowing.in/tools/parsing-logs-with-grok-1-what-to-do-when-part-of-one-field-got-caught-in-a-different-pattern/), might be helpful because your `class` field seems to contain too much info